# Is there any way to call a specific value or dataframe from another notebook in databricks?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to access a specific table from one notebook using another in databricks.

I use `dbutils.notebook.run('notebook_name', 60, parameters)` with a for loop. I do not know how to get that specific table/value from the first notebook

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html